# merging columns database diagram

Tags: database-design, entity-relationship, database-schema

I have a model where we import changes lets say,

A person has fixed attributes - Name, Eye colour
Changing attributes : Height, weight,age

I am trying to come up with the best solution for these changes.

Solution 1:

```
Table1: Person , Columns: Name,EyeColour
Table2: WeightChange: PersonId(FK), ChangeDate, FromWeight, ToWeight
Table3: OtherChange: PersonId(FK), ChangeDate, ChangeType(height or age), FinalState
```

Solution 2:

```
Table1: Person , Columns: Name,EyeColour
Table2: WeightChange: PersonId(FK), ChangeDate, FromWeight, ToWeight
Table3: HeightChange: PersonId(FK), ChangeDate, FinalState
Table4: AgeChange: PersonId(FK), ChangeDate, FinalState
```

If possible, could anyone please give me explanation on which method would be better or any other alternative approach ?

Thanks

Comment: Why don't you store the birthday so you can compute the age?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd remove the "from" column, use only one "Change" table and link it to a foreign table with "ChangeType" like:

```
Table1: Person , Columns: Name,EyeColour
Table2: Change: PersonId(FK), Type(FK) ChangeDate, Value
Table3: ChangeType: TypeDescription
```

if you'd need to retrieve values in a historical way, then you just need to query them using "ChangeDate" column to sort them and handle the output accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should just store the birth date rather than 1 entry per year on the person's birthday. If for some reason you do not have this value available, then solution 2 would be preferred. No need to combine them in one table. Or you could have a single table with all changes. Your first suggestion is between these two options.

You need to minimize the risk of inconsistency in your data. It is very easy to end up in a situation where *today* you have a weight from 80kg to 82kg, and *tomorrow* from 81kg to 83kg. This does not make much sense. You should just store each individual data point (toWeight). If you graph this data, you should interpolate between your data points to get a continous function.